# Firefox doesn't open when run on Jenkins server in headless mode

Tags: java, selenium, firefox, jenkins, cucumber

Firefox doesn't open when run on Jenkins server in headless mode. It gives the following error log. I'm using Firefox 55 and selenium 3.6.0

```
1511524678151   geckodriver INFO    geckodriver 0.19.0
1511524678162   geckodriver INFO    Listening on 127.0.0.1:24440
1511524678479   mozrunner::runner   INFO    Running command: "/usr/local/firefox/firefox" "-marionette" "-profile" 

"/tmp/rust_mozprofile.X3S4fow8aJXO"
        1511524678981   Marionette  INFO    Enabled via --marionette

        (firefox:7518): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_object_ref: assertion 'object->ref_count > 0' failed

        (firefox:7518): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_object_unref: assertion 'object->ref_count > 0' failed

        (firefox:7518): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_object_ref: assertion 'object->ref_count > 0' failed

        (firefox:7518): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_object_unref: assertion 'object->ref_count > 0' failed

        (/usr/local/firefox/firefox:7577): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_object_ref: assertion 'object->ref_count > 0' failed

        (/usr/local/firefox/firefox:7577): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_object_unref: assertion 'object->ref_count > 0' failed

        (/usr/local/firefox/firefox:7577): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_object_ref: assertion 'object->ref_count > 0' failed

        (/usr/local/firefox/firefox:7577): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_object_unref: assertion 'object->ref_count > 0' failed
        1511524680359   Marionette  INFO    Listening on port 48472
        1511524680397   Marionette  WARN    TLS certificate errors will be ignored for this session
        JavaScript error: chrome://marionette/content/server.js, line 337: NS_ERROR_SOCKET_ADDRESS_IN_USE: Component returned failure code: 0x804b0036 (NS_ERROR_SOCKET_ADDRESS_IN_USE) [nsIServerSocket.initSpecialConnection]
        1511524680436   Marionette  DEBUG   loaded listener.js
        Nov 24, 2017 11:58:00 AM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
        INFO: Detected dialect: W3C
        DEBUG   2017-11-24 11:58:00,576 [main] com.wso2telco.tests.apimanager.base.BasicTestObject  - FireFox LauncheBrowser method finished
        DEBUG   2017-11-24 11:58:00,576 [main] com.wso2telco.tests.apimanager.base.BasicTestObject  - FireFox Maximizing
        DEBUG   2017-11-24 11:58:00,598 [main] com.wso2telco.tests.apimanager.base.BasicTestObject  - Screenshor Captured
        DEBUG   2017-11-24 11:58:00,688 [main] com.wso2telco.tests.apimanager.base.BasicTestObject  - FireFox Maximized
        1511524680767   Marionette  INFO    New connections will no longer be accepted
```

What is the reason that Firefox doesn't run?

Answer (score 0):

**Update your Firefox browser**. This issue was resolved in FF-56.0 .

Comment: i also updated to 56 and 57 and same issue was found

Comment: Update the geckodriver too . From [here](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases)